# Метод частичного обновления dex

Tags: java, android, apk

Слышал про метод частичного обновления в Андроиде. Мол можно добавлять новые классы в имеющийся декс. Подскажите как это можно делать?

Comment: Dex это скомпилированный код приложения! Вы ошиблись форумом, реверс­-инжинирингом тут не занимаются вроде.

Comment: Забыл добавить, мне это нужно сделать на устройстве) То есть это делается java кодом. Скомпилированное приложение можно частично обновлять добавляя в него свои классы.